# Determining whether $\{f : \deg f = 0 \text{ or } \deg f = n\}$ is a subspace of the vector space of polynomials over a field.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is the set $$W = \{ f(x) \in P(F) : f(x) = 0 \text{ or } \deg f = n \}$$ a subspace of $P(F)$ if $n\geq 1 $?

The solution says it is not, as the set is not closed under addition.

But if we consider two elements of $W$, say $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, which are either $0$ or have degree $n$, then $f(x) + g(x)$ also either is $0$ or has degree $n$. So, $P(F)$ is a vector space of polynomial functions over a field $F$.

Where am I wrong?
Kindly help!

Comment: No. Take $f(x)=1+x^n$  and $g(x)=1-x^n$.

Comment: @Bernard your counterexmple is not correct, as the sum has degree 0.

Comment: @mookid actually the point is , if we take two functions of degree " n "then on adding these functions , the degree must be " n " and thus it would belong to W , which in this case isn't.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it *is* a counter-example to your assertion that $f(x)+g(x)$ is a polynomial that either has degree $n$  or is $0$: it doesn't fall into one of these cases.

Comment: @Bernard what I wanted to say, is that it is still an element of $W$.

Comment: The O.P. mentioned polynomials of degree $n$ (exactly) or the zero polynomials, not polynomials of degree $\le n$.